# how to pass $(this) to jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, parameter-passing

I am trying to use Jquery Cookie to achieve this. 
Once ".preview" is clicked, it leads to another page, but when user comes back, I want their visited lists to be highlighted. Hence they know which one they have browsed before.
NOTE: It'd be great if there are other way to achieve this without using Cookie.
thank you

```
 $('.Preview').click(function() {
    $.cookie('test', '1');
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('test') == '1') {
        $(???).css('background-color', '#eeeeee');
    }
});
```

Comment: You cannot store an object to a cookie. Give all elements persistent and unique `id` and store/select by id

Comment: How about using CSS? Assuming the elements are `<a>`nchors - `.preview:visited { background-color: #eee; }`

Comment: Can we not able to use their index number to achieve this?

Comment: Phil, unfortunately that's not an option for me

Comment: Maybe some localStorage would be more appropriate? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

You can save JSON object into cookie but there is kind of hack its not direct object saving but you can save it as string and parse it as JSON object and use it.

```
function savecookie()
{
    var cdata = new Array("data1", "data2")
    var data = "{\"one\":\"" + cdata[0] + "\", \"two\":\"" + cdata[1] + "\"}";
    createCookie("Data", data, 1);
}

function printcookie()
{
    var c = readCookie("Data");
    c = unescape(c);
    var cdata = jQuery.parseJSON(c);
    $("#val").html(cdata.two + "  " + cdata.one);
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zQnwA/1/)

Comment: Just a quick tip - there is no need to use `<pre>` and `<code>` tags when inserting code into your answer. Simply indent 4 spaces or use the "format code" button.

Comment: Thanks! though i tried that but some how i still messed it up :) will keep in mind next time.

Comment: how would you exactly solve the question by using above code? I am not familiar with jason.

Comment: i updated the dmeo link hope this will give idea how to use it !! json is not diff can find tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/json/